# How do I track the amount of commands executed in a given time?

Tags: batch-file

I have a dummy password cracking software, to play around with, and I was wondering if there was a way I could track how many commands were executed in a given time for a counter for the brute force portion of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out. Basically just do something along the lines of

```
:idk
set /A count=1 + count
cls
echo %count% commands executed 
echo put something here
if %count%==put a number here to stop at (
goto :(next thing)
) else (
goto :idk
```